# Можно ли Visual Studio целиком установить на единственный диск?

Tags: visual-studio

При попытке установить Visual Studio на отдельный диск, она все равно устанавливает несколько ГБ на системный диск...

Можно ли целиком установить VS на диск, который не системы?

Comment: думаю можно как то извернуться, но это не рекомендуется

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Некоторые компоненты **обязаны** устанавливаться именно в %SystemRoot%[\System32].